# How to determine if an object in an image is a planar or non-planar surface?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Assume I have a multiple images of an object taken from different camera perspectives ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KYNX.png)). The object is either a real, physical object (non-planar surface) or a fake object (planar surface), such as a painting/picture of an object. ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mZpD.jpg))

So, how can I determine if the object is planar or non-planar?

I'm using OpenCV. I don't need the code, just guidance in this area. Thank you.

Comment: from 2D projected image, its hard to determine the real 3D point as the depth Z is lost in the projection process. One thing you can do is to ask the user to move head from left to right or right to left based on random instruction. So that you can check whether it is a photo or real person moving its head. the idea is called strcture from motion.  however, i do still recommend you to mount on devices such as stereo, RGBD system to verify it has valid depth.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai "One thing you can do is to ask the user to move head from left to right or right to left based on random instruction." this is what I have. I have multiple images from different camera perspectives. How do I know if an object is real or fake from the structure of motion idea?

Comment: try to reconstruct them in 3D based on the input 2D. Based on the reconstrcuted 3D. you can check the reprojected 2D image with the source 2D image. to see the difference. if the difference is too high, then liekly the source 2D image if fake